# How to split a data frame based on one variable and create cross table separetely between other two variable separately for first variable?

Tags: r

My dataset: df

```
PID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)  
gender<-c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)  
smoking<-c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)  
disease<-c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)  
BMI<-c(24,23,21,28,29,21,18,19,16)    
 df<-data.frame(PID, gender, smoking, disease, BMI)
```

I want to split this dataset based on gender. Then develop crosstab between smoking and disease. How to do this?
**Expected outcome(first question):**
Gender:1
crosstab between smoking and disease

Gender:2
Crosstab between smoking and disease.

**Expected outcome (second question):**

Gender:1
mean of BMI

Gender:2
mean of BMI

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I'd think `xtabs` and `aggregate` should answer both questions.

Answer (score 2):

No need for external packages:

```
xtabs(~smoking+disease+gender,data=df)
# , , gender = 0
#        disease
# smoking 0 1
#       0 1 2
#       1 1 0
# , , gender = 1
#        disease
# smoking 0 1
#       0 0 2
#       1 2 1
aggregate(df$BMI, list(gender=df$gender), FUN=mean)
#   gender     x
# 1      0 22.25
# 2      1 22.00
```

Similarly (thanks thelatemail):

```
aggregate(BMI ~ gender, data = df, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: `aggregate(BMI ~ gender, data=df, FUN=mean)` might be a bit more readable and keep the consistent formula interface. Or even `aggregate(df["BMI"], df["gender"], FUN=mean)` if the formulas are not to your taste.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way for the first question using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)


> df %>% split(gender) %>% lapply(function(x) tab=xtabs(gender~smoking+disease, data=x))
$`0`
       disease
smoking 0 1
      0 0 0
      1 0 0

$`1`
       disease
smoking 0 1
      0 0 2
      1 2 1
```

Comment: You really don't need `dlpyr` here ... `xtabs(~smoking+disease+gender,data=df)` does effectively the same thing